# iPhone photos unidirectional sync?

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization, photos, image-capture

How can I get all *new* photos/movies added to my iPhone to be auto-downloaded into a specified folder each time I connect the iPhone to my Mac? (without deleting the downloaded photos/movies from the iPhone)

The "Image Capture" and "AutoImporter" apps seem to only be able to download *all* photos each time, which means that unless I choose the "Delete after import" option, I get many duplicates for each import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The forum build of DropBox will do that for you. I'm not sure if you can specify exactly what folder (by default it goes in a folder called 'Camera Imports' in your dropbox folder). It will even earn you more space.

http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=57787&replies=7